# jquery jqrowl get message from getjson

Tags: jquery, json, jgrowl

first thing first, im a PHP developer and im trying to learn jquery (javascript) and so far ive learn a lot but im a bit lost.

json output.

```
{"msg": [{"message":"blah", "header":"title of blah"}, {"message":"blah", "header":"title of blah"}]}
```

i made it like because i wanted something like this.

```
$message = blah

$header = title of blah
```

and not

```
message = message

header = header
```

which is what im getting by using ....

```
$.getJSON("json.php", function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
$.jGrowl(key, { 
life: 5000,
header: val,
});
});
});
```

i know, i need to add another `$.each` and this is where im lost a bit. i need something more like this but in javascript.

```
$msg = array("message" => 'blah', "header" => 'title blah' );

$message = $msg['message']; // blah
$header = $msg['header']; // title of blah
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what error you are facing . can u put that on a fiddle ?

Comment: i would but im not getting an error. im trying to figure out or learn how to do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand it well. But you don't need 1 more "each" loop I think. Does the code below suit you ?

```
$.getJSON("json.php", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  // if you only put data as input, data variable is an array like [data, textStatus, jqXHR] I think. Thus the "each" function returns you the data, the status and the xhr I think
  $.each(data.msg, function(index, value) {
    // for each entry of the msg array, create a notification. "value" is a {"header": "...", "content": "..."} object
    $.jGrowl(
      value.message, // here is the notification's content
      {
        group: "myhtmlclass",
        life: 5000,
        header: value.header, // here is the notification's title
      }
    });
  });
});
```